# ml_core and ml_core.ensemble API doc and examples

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, fast-ai

I came accross a sample code like below. I wanted to look for API and Doc around this package   ml_core , ml_core.ensemble , could some one post the link ?

```
from ml_core.ensemble import Ensemble
    class myEnsemble(Ensemble):
       def preprocess(predict():
           # Code
       def predict():
          # Code
       def def postprocess():
           #Code
    ensemble = myEnsemble()
    ensemble.predict(..)
```